# How to refactor this Emacs lisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs-faces

I'm not quite down with the syntax for dynamic symbols etc. I guess I can probably do something with `dolist` and a list of colors here, but not sure what:

```
  (custom-set-faces
   `(term-color-black ((t (:inherit term-color-black :background ,(face-attribute 'term-color-black :foreground)))))
   `(term-color-red ((t (:inherit term-color-red :background ,(face-attribute 'term-color-red :foreground)))))
   `(term-color-green ((t (:inherit term-color-green :background ,(face-attribute 'term-color-green :foreground)))))
   `(term-color-yellow ((t (:inherit term-color-yellow :background ,(face-attribute 'term-color-yellow :foreground)))))
   `(term-color-blue ((t (:inherit term-color-blue :background ,(face-attribute 'term-color-blue :foreground)))))
   `(term-color-magenta ((t (:inherit term-color-magenta :background ,(face-attribute 'term-color-magenta :foreground)))))
   `(term-color-cyan ((t (:inherit term-color-cyan :background ,(face-attribute 'term-color-cyan :foreground)))))
   `(term-color-white ((t (:inherit term-color-white :background ,(face-attribute 'term-color-white :foreground))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not 100% identical, but in most cases will be equivalent:

```
(defmacro set-term-faces (names)
  `(custom-set-faces
    ,@(loop for color in names
         for sym = (intern (concat "term-color-" (symbol-name color)))
         collect (list 'quote
                       `(,sym ((t (:inherit ,sym
                                   :background
                                   ,(face-attribute sym :foreground)))))))))

(set-term-faces (black red green yellow blue magenta cyan white))
```

The discrepancy is at the point of when the evaluation of `,(face-attribute ...)` happens. I.e. this macro doesn't produce the same source code you have, it already evaluates the expression after comma, so if your code was inside a macro, that would make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* refactor that code, but you probably shouldn't. All `(custom-set-...)` code is generated automatically by Emacs' "[easy customization](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html#Easy-Customization)" system. Thus if you refactor it, there is a good chance that

1. you break compatibility with the customization system
2. your refactored code will be overwritten by the original code next time you customize a face

However, if you find your .emacs file too cluttered, you can configure Emacs to write customization code to a separate file. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5058752/261142) to a related question, and also Emacs' [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Customizations.html).

Comment: That code wasn't written by `customize` - I wrote it myself. I'm just using `custom-set-faces` to override some things.

Comment: In that case, you can use `set-face-attribute` directly.

Comment: ...or `defface`, for that matter.